# Proving if $2^n + n^2$ is a prime, show that $n ≡ 3 \pmod 6$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, congruences

**If $n$ is a positive integer greater than $1$ such that $2^n + n^2$ is a prime, show that $n ≡ 3 \pmod 6$**

*Source of the question : http://math.stanford.edu/~paquin/ModPS.pdf*

I tried this for hours but couldn't prove it.

My conclusions are

1. $n$ is odd.
2. $2^n + n^2  ≡ 1\pmod 4$

Thank you for everyone in advance!
Pl. help me.

Comment: I think you just have to sub in $n=6m+1,2,4,5,6$, and as SiXUlm mentions, consider them mod 2 and mod 3

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea, thanks snulty and SiXUlm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n \equiv 0,2,4 \pmod 6$ then that sum is divisible by $2$.

If $n \equiv 1,5 \pmod 6$ then that sum is divisible by $3$.